# MCMC Sample should be i.i.d

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, iid

I'm a bit not sure how to show that MCMC samples are i.i.d. In my opinion the trace plot should behave like white noise model because white noise model has a strong stationary properties i.e. the joint distribution from any lag is the same hence the identical distribution achieve. Is it correct ? And if one see the ACF plot one need to see whether the ACF are exponentially decreasing. But 0 correlation or 0 covariance doesn't imply independence, so how to proof it ?

Answer (score 3):

MCMC chains do not generate independent samples. To convince yourself, look at the autocorrelation plots, the autocorrelations would be non-zero. That is why one of the metrics we use for judging the quality of the results we use metrics as effective sample size that tries to estimate how many independent samples does your chain contain.

Comment: I thought that sample observation should be i.i.d. ? And also if the autocorrelations is below the significance level, one can conclude that the correlation is zero. Is it an exception for gibbs sampling or other sampling technique in MCMC ?

Comment: @actscistudtries2learnmath you want them to be close to i.i.d. but they are not.

Comment: I get it now ! Thank you so much

Comment: "Sample observations are iid" does not contradict "MCMC samples are not iid"

Comment: but mcmc is a method to sample from a (posterior) distribution should it be iid as well ?

Comment: @actscistudtries2learnmath we would like that, but producing independent samples would be excessively slow. We take almost independent samples, but with a sampler that is faster.